# Apache Camel components: jcache vs ehcache vs caffeine-cache

Tags: java, apache-camel, ehcache, jcache, caffeine-cache

What is the main difference between [jcache-component](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/jcache-component.html), [ehcache-component](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/ehcache-component.html) and [caffeine-cache-component](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/caffeine-cache-component.html) (or any other); and which one would be the most appropriate for a simple use case in Apache Camel?

---

The problem:

I need to read a relatively large `CSV` file, `split` it and insert each row somewhere via a `REST` service. The service requires an authentication token that expires in a few minutes, so it is possible to insert multiple records with the same token, but not all.

Therefore, I want to `cache` the authentication `token` (a simple string) to reuse it (say for 100 records, or maybe 1 minute) and then get a new token. Note that since the `split` creates a new `exchange` for each iteration, you cannot use `headers` or `properties` to share information (the authentication token) between iterations.

```
from("timer://runOnce?repeatCount=1")
    .to("direct:read-csv-data")
    .split(body())
        .to("direct:set-authorization")
        .to("direct:insert-data-rest")
    .end();

from("direct:set-authorization")
    .choice()
        .when(this::requiresAuthorizationRenewal).to("direct:get-authorization-and-save-in-cache")
        .otherwise().to("direct:get-authorization-from-cache")
    .end();
```

*(The `requiresAuthorizationRenewal` predicate uses the `CamelSplitIndex` exchange property to determine when to renew the token, e.g., every 100 records)*